# Cannot convert Dictionary to JSON object using json.dumps() in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to convert a dictionary using `json.dumps()`

```
def create_custom(json_input):
    custom = dict()
    custom['list'] = dict()
    custom['list']['Elements'] = json_input['nodes']
    custom['list']['links'] = json_input['links']
    return custom

JsonData = create_custom(json_graph.node_link_data(G))

for i, j in enumerate(Elements):
    JsonData['list']['Elements'][i]['Shape'] = j['Shape']
```

The above code is not complete but the final output I am getting is a dictionary

**Output**

```
{'list': {'Elements': [{'text': 'Task 1', 'Shape': 'Decision', 'id': 0},
   {'text': 'Task 2', 'Shape': 'Decision', 'id': 1},
   {'text': 'Task 3', 'Shape': 'Decision', 'id': 2},
   {'text': 'Task 4', 'Shape': 'Decision', 'id': 3},
   {'text': 'Task 5', 'Shape': 'Rectangle', 'id': 4},
   {'text': 'Task 6', 'Shape': 'Decision', 'id': 5}],
  'links': [{'source': 0, 'target': 1, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 0, 'target': 4, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 1, 'target': 2, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 1, 'target': 3, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 2, 'target': 1, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 2, 'target': 4, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 3, 'target': 1, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 3, 'target': 4, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 4, 'target': 5, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 5, 'target': 4, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 5, 'target': 1, 'key': 0}]}}
```

When I am converting the above output to JSON object

```
json.dumps(JsonData)
```

I am getting an error:

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in default(self, o)
    177 
    178         """
--> 179         raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    180                         f'is not JSON serializable')
    181 

TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable
```

I went across many answers but they are saying about `numpy array` etc.

Where I am going wrong

Comment: Check the type of your int in JSON. It's probably a numpy.int64 type. Try converting the entire JSON to string and then dumping it.

Comment: @deadshot I am converting that dictionary into JSON the sample which I have provided is a dictionary object.

Comment: @JacobCelestine I tried the same I am getting `'"{\'list\': {\'Elements\': [{\'text\': \'Task 1\', \'Shape\': \'Decision\'` which is not a proper format

Comment: Only 1 person at this point knows what `json_graph.node_link_data(G)` and `Elements` means. You need to provide this.

Comment: @GustavRasmussen  https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.json_graph.node_link_data.html
you can check it returns a dictionary by which I am creating my own custom dictionary and converting it into json

Comment: Is it correct that you wish to take the object under `OUTPUT` and transform it into valid JSON ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not recreate the error, but `json.dumps` worked fine for me. Please refer to the screenshot below:

[image: Code sample and output]

Code I tried:

```
import json
JsonData={'list': {'Elements': [{'text': 'Task 1', 'Shape': 'Decision', 'id': 0},
   {'text': 'Task 2', 'Shape': 'Decision', 'id': 1},
   {'text': 'Task 3', 'Shape': 'Decision', 'id': 2},
   {'text': 'Task 4', 'Shape': 'Decision', 'id': 3},
   {'text': 'Task 5', 'Shape': 'Rectangle', 'id': 4},
   {'text': 'Task 6', 'Shape': 'Decision', 'id': 5}],
  'links': [{'source': 0, 'target': 1, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 0, 'target': 4, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 1, 'target': 2, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 1, 'target': 3, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 2, 'target': 1, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 2, 'target': 4, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 3, 'target': 1, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 3, 'target': 4, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 4, 'target': 5, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 5, 'target': 4, 'key': 0},
   {'source': 5, 'target': 1, 'key': 0}]}}
print(type(JsonData))
print(json.dumps(JsonData))
print(type(json.dumps(JsonData)))
```

Comment: @vivek Use this: `print(json.dumps(str(JsonData)))` instead of `JsonData`

Comment: json.dumps needs `int`, not `numpy.int64`. So here I am converting the entire thing to a string.